# Maximum likelihood estimator of a discretized exponential random sample

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ a random sample of lifetime of a type of components with  exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. Suppose that observations have a precision of $2h$, i.e., a component have timelife $x_0$ if fails in interval $(x_0-h,x_0+h)$. Find the Maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta.$

**My attempt**

I think is possible to write the likelihood function as
$L(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\Pi_{i=1}^nP(X_i\in(x_i-h,x_i+h)|\theta)$

since each $X_i$ is exponential with mean $\theta$

$P(X_i\in(x_i-h,x_i+h)|\theta)=F(x_i+h)-F(x_i-h)=1-e^\frac{-x_i-h}{\theta}-1+e^\frac{-x_i+h}{\theta}=e^\frac{-x_i}{\theta}(e^\frac{h}{\theta}-e^\frac{-h}{\theta}).$

So

$L(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\Pi_{i=1}^n e^\frac{-x_i}{\theta}(e^\frac{h}{\theta}-e^\frac{-h}{\theta})=e^-\frac{\sum x_i}{\theta}(e^\frac{h}{\theta}-e^\frac{-h}{\theta})^n.$

I'm trying to find the maximum solving the equation $\frac{d}{d\theta}L=0$ but I can't solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a component have timelife $x_0$ if fails in interval $(x_0-h,x_0+h)$". For a given failure time of a given component, there is a range of values of $x_0$ such that the failure time lies in that interval. It's not clear how one of these $x_0$ is chosen.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is the following (?): $T$ is the real lifetime with an exponential distribution. Given $T$, we observe $X$ uniformly in $(T-h,T+h)$.

Comment: This problem is part of an exercise whose objective is to compare the $\theta$ estimate when we consider that $x_i$ is observed with a point probability defined as $P (x_i | \theta)=P(x_i-h\leq X_i \leq x_i+h|\theta)$ with the usual MLE, and analize wath happens when $h\rightarrow 0.$